# Как полностью удалить npm и gulp на windows?

Tags: gulp, npm

Пишет, что `npm` не является внутренней или внешней командой (пытался и в корневой папке, тоже самое).

Хочу удалить и заново переустановить.

Comment: nodejs надо удалить, npm его часть. через установку/удаление программ